# GraphViz: How can i add image to html label

Tags: graphviz

i need to add image to html label, any sugestions how can i do that?

```
 St1_U41 [
   shape=plaintext
  
   label=< 
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
        //i need image right here
        <tr><td colspan="10">St1, U41</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="10">Huawei</td></tr>
       <tr><td port='34'>34</td><td port='36'>36</td><td port='38'>38</td><td port='37'>37</td><td port='40'>40</td><td port='39'>39</td><td port='47'>47</td><td port='48'>48</td><td port='49'>49</td><td port='51'>51</td></tr>
     </table>
  >];
```

Answer (score 0):

added a **<TD** and **<IMG** (see http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#images-example)

```
graph 1 {

St1_U41 [
   shape=plaintext
  
   label=< 
     <table border='1' cellborder='1'>
       <tr><td colspan="10"><IMG SRC="HELLO.png"/></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="10">St1, U41</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="10">Huawei</td></tr>
       <tr><td port='34'>34</td><td port='36'>36</td><td port='38'>38</td><td port='37'>37</td><td port='40'>40</td><td port='39'>39</td><td port='47'>47</td><td port='48'>48</td><td port='49'>49</td><td port='51'>51</td></tr>
     </table>
     >];
}
```

Giving:
[image: HTML-label with image made with GraphViz]